# Is it possible to cache an entire HTML5 video using the Service Worker API for offline use?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache, service-worker

I have an offline app that caches all static resources.  Currently, only the first 15 seconds of video assets are cached.

Below shows basic implementations of the `install` and `fetch` event listeners.

**Service Worker:**

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('v1').then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/',
        '/videos/one.mp4',
        '/videos/two.mp4'
      ]);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(response => {
      if (response) return response;
      return fetch(event.request);
    });
  );
});
```

And in `index.html`

```
<video controls preload>
  <source src="/videos/one.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: maybe you can convert the video to a blob and save the blob. [this](https://simpl.info/video/offline/) seems to have some relevant techniques

Comment: Cache API service workers use [stores request/response pairs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/put#Parameters). So I doubt if there is any file type limitation. [Quote:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) `...a storage mechanism for Request / Response object pairs that are cached...`

Comment: In fact I have put it to test and it works great, as expected. [You can check it here](https://lazysheepherd.com/sw-test/offline/)

Comment: @UmurKaragöz Thank you, I did too and it does work great.  (I've just posted an answer including code)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I used the following steps to accomplish offline video on the first page load without first watching the entire video(s).

1. Register a service worker and cache all requests. Static assets are just `'/'` for this case.  If you inspect the service worker's `fetch` event, you'll see that subsequent requests are also cached.
2. Use the `fetch` API to request a video as a `blob`.

**Example using fetch to request a video as a blob**

```
const videoRequest = fetch('/path/to/video.mp4').then(response => response.blob());
videoRequest.then(blob => {
  ...
});
```

3. Use the `IndexedDB` API to store the `blob`.  (Use `IndexedDB` instead of `LocalStorage` to avoid blocking the main thread while storing.)

That's it!  Now when in offline mode, the service worker will intercept requests and serve both the `html` and `blob` from cache.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Service Worker Test</h1>

  <p>Try reloading the page without an Internet connection.</p>

  <video controls></video>

  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then(registration => {
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', error);
        });
      });
    } else {
      alert('serviceWorker is not in navigator');
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    const videos = {
      one: document.querySelector('video')
    };

    const videoRequest = fetch('/path/to/video.mp4').then(response => response.blob());
    videoRequest.then(blob => {
      const request = indexedDB.open('databaseNameHere', 1);

      request.onsuccess = event => {
        const db = event.target.result;

        const transaction = db.transaction(['videos']);
        const objectStore = transaction.objectStore('videos');

        const test = objectStore.get('test');

        test.onerror = event => {
          console.log('error');
        };

        test.onsuccess = event => {
          videos.one.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(test.result.blob);
        };
      }

      request.onupgradeneeded = event => {
        const db = event.target.result;
        const objectStore = db.createObjectStore('videos', { keyPath: 'name' });

        objectStore.transaction.oncomplete = event => {
          const videoObjectStore = db.transaction('videos', 'readwrite').objectStore('videos');
          videoObjectStore.add({name: 'test', blob: blob});
        };
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Service Worker**

```
const latest = {
  cache: 'some-cache-name/v1'
};

self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(latest.cache).then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll([
        '/'
      ]);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  // exclude requests that start with chrome-extension://
  if (event.request.url.startsWith('chrome-extension://')) return;
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open(latest.cache).then(cache => {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(response => {
        var fetchPromise = fetch(event.request).then(networkResponse => {
          cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
          return networkResponse;
        })
        return response || fetchPromise;
      })
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.filter(cacheName => {
          if (cacheName === latest.cache) {
            return false;
          }

          return true;
        }).map(cacheName => {
          return caches.delete(cacheName)
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

**Resources:**

- [Excellent course on Service Workers & IndexedDB](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud899/)
- [Using fetch for requestType blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob)
- [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)
- [Example using IndexedDB to store a blob](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/)

Comment: Hi @Raphael Rafatpanah,I am trying to do this for mutliple videos,is there any way of achieving this,basically I want to save a total of 5 videos in indexeddb and be able to list the videos in the browser so that I can click and play them while offline.

Comment: As long as the device has enough disc space, it might be doable. You may run into issues on iOS since I believe there are stricter storage limits compared to Chrome  Here's an example to get you started: https://github.com/persianturtle/offline-first-example

Comment: wont it create an issue for large size file, what if my video is more then 200 or 300 MB, it will first load the complete video then render it, it will take more than a minute